# CSS: Clickable Li (text-indent link)

Tags: css

I have classes on list items that have background images. I want to text indent the anchor tag text and make the entire list item clickable. I am unable to change the markup and the class with the background needs to be applied to the li and not the a. Thanks!

```
<ul>
    <li> <a href="#">Link One </a></li>
    <li> <a href="#">Link Two </a></li>
</ul>

ul {
  list-style:none;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  text-indent: -999px;
  background-color: lime;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
li a {
  text-indent: -9900px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: remove text-indent from li, so a tag is there , else it's gone -999px left away :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/9g0wja63/2/)

**CSS**

```
ul {
  list-style:none;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: lime;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

li a {
  text-indent: -9900px;
  height: 100px; /* let the size of the link determine the li size */
  width: 100px;
  display: block; /* this is the vital part */
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew it something painfully simple :)